# How to show custom error messages to the user?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I've got a simple extension that validates article pages by ensuring that all pages with specific categories contain specific templates within them. My checking happens in an `onPageContentSave` function.

I followed the documentation and used $status->fatal(), and return false to abort the save. However, nothing is shown to the user, so they won't have any idea what's wrong.

What I've tried:

```
public static function onPageContentSave($wikiPage, $user, $content, $summary, $isMinor, $isWatch, $section, $flags, $status) { 

    $content = $content->getNativeData();
    $response = self::httpPost("http://api.oneorzero.org:9999/theo", ['data' => json_encode(['wikiPage' => $wikiPage, 'user' => $user, 'content' => $content, 'summary' => $summary, 'isWatch' => $isWatch, 'section' => $section, 'flags' => $flags, 'status' => $status])]);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    $continue = false;
    if(json_encode($response) == '{"message":"success"}') {

        $continue = true;
    } else {

        $status->fatal( new RawMessage(json_encode($response)));
    }

    // $response should be true on success, and false on fail
    // false cancels the article save
    return $continue;
}
```

This code works with the exception of the RawMessage never being shown to users.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is the correct approach (other than PageContentSave being deprecated since MediaWiki 1.35, with MultiContentSave as a replacement; but it does still work), so chances are you have a bug in your code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want *[AbuseFilter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter)*. Define a rule that shows an error message (you can choose, which), if a user tries to save a page with a category and without a template instead of saving the page, something like this:

```
action == 'edit'
& new_wikitext irlike '\[\[category:your_category(\|[^\]]*)?\]\]'
& !new_wikitext irlike '\{\{your_template(\|[^}]*)?\}\}'
```

1. The first condition will be applied only on page editing/creation.
2. It will check, case-insensitively, the new wikitext of the page against a regular expression that is supposed to find assignments to the category `Your_category`.
3. Finally, it will check whether the new wikitext contains a call to the template `{{Your_template}}`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. You solution does seem like a good solution. I think I found a better solution myself. I added it to this question. Sorry for wasting your time with the question. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a solution to my question, so I'll just leave it here for anyone else:

The solution is to use a different hook called `onEditFilter`. This hook has a built in method to show a custom error message to users, and functions similarly to `onPageContentSave`.

Here's a link to the hook's documentation: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/EditFilter

And here's an example:

```
public static function onEditFilter($editor, $text, $section, &$error, $summary) { 

    $response = self::httpPost("http:/api.oneorzero.org:9999/theo", ['data' => json_encode(['wikiPage' => $text])]);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    if ($response == '') {

        $error = '<li class="edit-error">' . "ERROR: The edit validation service cannot be reached. Please contact User:Jobgh to get this issue resolved." . "</li>";
        return true;
    }

    if (json_encode($response) != '{"message":"success"}') {

        $error = '<li class="edit-error">' . $response['message'] . "</li>";
    }

    // Return value should be true on success and fail. Set $error to cancel the save and show an error to the user
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Will your solution work if only one section is edited, and the category and needed template are in different sections?

Comment: EditFilter is specific to normal editing (as opposed to, say, programmatically generated edits). It will only provide the contents of the edit form, not necessarily the whole article, and in the exact form it was entered int the form (no pre-save transform or edit conflict resolution). Those might be good or bad things, depending on your use case.

Comment: Also EditFilter runs way earlier than PageSaveComplete so performance-wise it will be a lot better if you can catch problems there (less delay before the user sees the error message). The flip side is that page rendering has not happened yet at the time EditFilter is called, so the list of categories and templates used on the page has not been calculated and you are left with fragile attempts to reproduce wikitext parsing.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin Thanks for the heads up! I’ll do some testing and get back to you guys today

Comment: You guys were right. Th filter doesn't work well if you edit a single section. I disabled section editing .